# Do I need to buy a Windows license to use WineHQ?

Tags: wine

I have heard that I can run Windows applications on Linux and other Unix platforms by using WineHQ. Will I need to buy a copy of Windows and install it inside of WineHQ, or does it somehow automagically run Windows applications without installing Windows, only installing WineHQ?

What version of Windows will I be effectively running if I use WineHQ (as of July 2017)? Does it behave like the latest version of Windows or some historical version? Can I change which version of Windows it simulates?

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to buy a MS Windows license.

Yes, Wine can simulate different versions of Windows.

From the [Wine User Guide](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main):

> Wine has the ability to mimic the behavior of different versions of Windows. In general, the biggest difference is whether Wine behaves as a Win9x version or an NT version. Some applications require a specific behavior in order to function and changing this setting may cause a buggy app to work. Wine default Windows version is Windows XP. Some applications may perform better if you choose Windows 98.